# Why isn't there a .= operator? (or ->= etc)

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Considering how often we do:

```
variable = variable + another;
variable = variable - another;
variable = variable * another;
variable = variable / another;
variable = variable & another;
variable = variable | another;
variable = variable ^ another;
```

we then made the following language shortcuts:

```
variable += another;
variable -= another;
variable *= another;
variable /= another;
variable &= another;
variable |= another;
variable ^= another;
```

so, then, considering how often we do this:

```
variable = variable.different();
// or variable = variable->different();
// or variable = variable::different();
```

(for instance, `stringVar = stringVar.toUpperCase()`), why isn't there one of these?

```
variable .= different();
// or variable ->= different();
// or variable ::= different();
```

is it a parsing issue? Would it be too hard? Or is there some obvious thing I don't see here?

I'm *not* asking for opinions, here.
I want to know if there's any documented, historic, technical, or other verifiable reasons for why there is no such operator.

Comment: This looks pretty subjective.  What kind of answer do you expect?  It might just have been an arbitrary decision made by language designers, for all I know.  We look for questions that will attract answers that [can be supported with facts, references, and evidence](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and that can be judged objectively based upon evaluation criteria specified in the question.  Maybe if you narrow it down to just asking about parsing...  As far as your question: Have you done any quantitative research?  How often *does* `variable = variable.different();` appear in code?

Comment: @D.W. And is it so often that replacing it with `variable.set_different()` would make more sense? (If `different()` is *only* used for updating the calling object, then using the assignment operator may not be the best syntax anyway.)

Comment: @D.W. I don't exactly know what you're asking... I was spurred by things like `string = string.toUpperCase()` if that helps. I've programmed in many languages and never seen one do anything like this, so that's my research. I was hoping someone could provide facts, references, and evidence as to why absolutely no languages do this, or if any do, which ones, and why they were able to do it but none of the more mainstream languages like C, C#, or Java.

Comment: @Supuhstar, I was asking if you've measured how often `x = x.m()` occurs in code, compared to `x = x + y` / `x += y`.  It's possible that language designers thought `x = x.m()` would be rare.  In C, I would expect it *is* rare.  But your example helps -- it suggests that this probably applies only to immutable types; for mutable types, we'd be more likely to use a different idiom, as Paul Clayton mentions.  For instance, maybe the designers of C figured it'd be rare, and the other languages just copied from C.  But this is speculation; I don't know how we'd ever get evidence.

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: I think that in some languages (e.g. Scala) creating such syntax (i.e. methods called like operators that look like syntax) is possible.

Comment: @Gilles I got this idea from using C-inspired languages from C++ to JavaScript, since those are what I most often use. Of course, this wouldn't apply to markup languages and the like. I don't have much experience in Scala, but I see that talked about here. I'd love to see some examples of a language that can do something like this!

Answer (score 6):

IMO, the biggest reason is that identifiers are not first class values in programming languages and "." is not a real operator like `+` or `-` are. For example, you can't convert

```
var foo = variable.bar()
```

into

```
var name = bar
var foo = variable.name()
```

The same way you can convert

```
var foo = 1 + 10
```

into

```
var x = 10
var foo = 1 + x
```

In more technical terms, in most languages `x + y` is an *expression*, while `x`, `x.y` and `x[i]` are *identifiers*.

Summing up, when using your hypothetical `.=`, the right hand side needs to be interpreted as a field name, not an expression. This leads to unintuitive results - the following two lines look very similar but do wildly different things.

```
x += bar() // calls the bar() global function and add its value to x
y .= bar() // calls y's bar() method, and sets `y` to its result.
```

---

Additionally, as Guy Coder pointed out, when using `+`, `-`, etc its guaranteed that the type of the resulting expression is the same as the arguments so `+=` always makes sense. On the other hand, we can have `y.bar()` return a type different from `y`, in which case `.= bar()` would make no sense.

Comment: Very nice pointing out the difference between expressions and identifiers! I'd forgotten about that entirely!

Comment: Identifiers aren't 1st class citizens in *most* programming languages. There are ones that do things right.

Comment: "when using +, -, etc its guaranteed that the type of the resulting expression is the same as the arguments" Not really, at least not in all languages. For example in C#, the result of adding two `byte`s is an `int`. Though this results in weird situations, where for example `b1 = b1 + b2;` doesn't compile, but `b1 += b2;` does.

Answer (score 3):

In the situtation: `variable += another;` you have 2 variables, 1 operator and 1 assignment.

In the situtation: `variable ->= different()` you have 1 variable, 1 method access operator ( i.e ->), 1 method name that needs to be called and 1 assignment.

When a language's *syntactic sugar* feature is designed, one important concept to consider is composition, i.e how elegantly you can compose these syntactic sugar based expressions.

In the first example you can create a chain of these operations:

```
variable *= another_var -= variable += another;
```

Whereas there is no simple way to do this kind of composition in the second case.
Lets say we have the below code:

```
variable = variable.method1();
another_var = variable.method2(params);
```

If you try to apply the approach that you suggested, you will get into weird situtation:

```
another_var .= <what should be here> variable .= method1()
```

In the method based case there is pattern called "fluent API design". You can use that to express the above code elegantly.

```
another_var = variable.method1().method2(params);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your example with chaining is good, but wouldn't that also break down if the first or any middle variable was actually a constant?

Comment: Any attempt at assignment to a constant would fail (after initialization). If you want to use a constant, don't try assigning to it, that's not what constants are for.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is not done is because the type of the result may not be the same as the type of the receiving term.

In the examples you gave the result and receiving terms are the same type or it is common to coerce the type of the result into the receiving term type which is common with mathematical operators.

Standard way
Int = Int + Int

Syntactic sugar
Int += Int

```
Receiving Term  Other Term  Result  
Int             Int         Int  
Float           Int         Float  
Float           Float       Float
```

If it is taken that -> means pointer then you would have

Standard way
Name = Person -> Name

Your way
Person ->= Name

```
Receiving Term  Other Term  Result  
Object          String      String
```

So setting an object to a string would either cause the type of the object to become a string which may not be desired or the compiler might throw an exception.

Standard way
Color = Bird -> Color

Your way
Bird ->= Color

```
Receiving Term  Other Term  Result
Bird            Color       Color
```

Obviously a bird should not be a color but can have a color.

Comment: I actually meant the "Standard way" to be `Color = Color->Bird`, and "my way" to be `Color ->= Bird`

Answer (score 2):

The simple thing is we rarely found this situation for using like this

```
 variable = variable.different();
// or variable = variable->different();
// or variable = variable::different();
```

since we call a function with objects and assign the return value to the variable and normally we never return an object back to the same in old days.

there fore the compiler designer will never think about giving special meaning to the `.=` or `->=`

but if you take the examples of arithmetic operators we will found this may be in every program like tormenting adding etc .

but when the concept of OOP is increased rapidly one need to think about giving such a special meaning..

Comment: So your perspective is that, in these use cases, you find it more common that `variable.different()` would be a mutating method, so such reassignment is unnecessary? Interesting - I was thinking of things like `myString.substring(2...5)`, which returns a value without mutating anything

Answer (score 1):

I would like to build on [hugomg](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28900/19611) with this example from JavaScript:

```js
var foo = variable.bar()
```

can be rewritten as

```js
var name = "bar";
var foo = variable[name]();
```

When it comes down to it, `.` is just as much an operator as `+`. It's a binary operator who's left side must be an object, and who's right side should be a property name in that object. In ES at least, for property names that don't fit the identifier requirements, there's a different notation that does the same thing.

Further, while `x` is an identifier and `y` is also an identifier, `x.y` is an expression, not significantly different from `1+2` except in how it is carried out. The simple fact that the `.` operation can be interfered with (via Proxy) is proof that `x.y` is not simply an identifier.

The real reason why `.=` is not an operator is simply that it makes code harder to read and understand, even for the engine. Consider this:

```js
function add(a=0, b=0) {
  return a + b;
}

some.preexisting.obj.with.an.add.function .= add(3);
```

This would be valid code, but confusing as heck. Without the dot in `.=`, the add function in this example would be called. However, with it, the add function belonging to that ridiculous object would be called. This goes against some basic understandings about the nature of ES function calls. In short, it's just a bad idea.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Prefer hyperlinking to an answer [like hugomg's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28900/19966) or comment you are referring to over stating an ordinal number, which may change.

Comment: Note that [hugomg's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28900/19966) continues to read *can't convert [plain access] into [two steps] **the same way** you can convert [plain access] into [two steps]*, if misleadingly capitalising `The same…`. (I think you are right pointing out the availability of mechanisms at the source code level with "object oriented languages conceptually interpreted". I think the argument from the question *does* apply to languages like C, especially those sporting [assignment operators beyond "basic"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment).)

Comment: Fascinating perspective on hugomg's answer - thank you for chipping in your 2¢! I think the most valuable thing you pointed out is that it would be difficult to disambiguate using a global function versus a member function in this context 